# Imported CSV into MySQL Table. Would only import as text, attempting to convert text to integers

Tags: mysql, truncate

1) I created a CSV with 2 columns, FoodID (names of food) & CaloriesPerOunce 
   (I removed both headers previous to importing).

2) MySQL would only import the CSV into my database if I set both data types 
   to "text". If I didn't set it to text, the data in the CaloriesPerOunce 
   column truncated.

3) Once I had my data imported into the table, I was able to change the FoodID 
   column data type to VARCHAR(45) and set it as a primary key.

4) I am unable to change the data in the CaloriesPerOunce column datatype to 
   "INT".  There are no Null values in the column.

I added an empty row "Calories" to the table through the Table View and set the datatype to INT, the attempted to copy the data from "CaloriesPerOunce" Column to "calories" and it again truncated at row 1.  I am really confused at to why I cannot change the datatype.

```
use nutrition;
ALTER TABLE food MODIFY FoodID VARCHAR(45);
ALTER TABLE food MODIFY CaloriesPerOunce int;


Use Nutrition;
UPDATE food SET calories = CaloriesPerOunce;
```

5) I attempted to change it through the Table view and through code.  Both 
   options give me "Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 
   'CaloriesPerOunce'at row 1."

```
FoodID             CaloriesPerOunce
Allblue Potatoes    17 
Alligator           65 
Almond Butter       172 
Almond Oil          265 
Alphabet Soup       7 
American Cheese     41 
Anchovy             37 
Angel Food Cake     72 
Apple Crisp         44
```

Comment: Kindly share the sample data used? btw are you trying to update `calories` column. Since that was what you have mentioned.

Comment: Please add your original table defintion, a few rows (or all of them if it's small) from your csv file (including headers) and share with us how you imported (via an ide,pyhton,php,load data infile...)

Comment: I'm not a nutrition expert so I have no idea how big(max length) in terms of digits CaloriesPerOunce can be? or if this is expressed as a real (eg 4.2) but you will get this error if you attempt to insert a string which starts with numbers and ends with alphas (eg '10zzz')

Comment: I am pretty novice.  The sample data has 2 columns and 931 rows. How can I share that with you?  The table only has those 2 columns with "FoodID" as the PK and the "CaloriesPerOunce" is only numeric no alphas.  It ranges from 0 to 200.

Comment: So you said data is been truncated? if so have you checked which row it affects?

Comment: I was importing the data through the Data Import Data wizard in MySQL Workbench, I am on a windows 10 machine, if that matters.

Comment: It truncates at row 1 in the CaloriesPerOunce column

Comment: If it truncates at row 1 just add your first 5 rows as text to the question.

Comment: This is a link to my food.csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kf2HTqx8ZXw5KWyBW8zCjIheqrUdM_Ap/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link is not a csv file (where's the comma column delimiters?) The most obvious suggestion is that you are not telling import to ignore/exclude the first row..

Comment: I am confused, the link my CSV I created with excel. And the table import wizard doesn't give you the option to ignore the first row, so prior to importing it, I deleted the first row, so there were no headers. I got the data into the table, and I was able to change the data type on the FoodID column to VARCHAR(45) and make it the PK. When I attempted to change the "CaloriesPerOunce" to Int from Text, that is when it truncates. I tried creating a second empty row and copying the data into that row and delete the original "CaloriesPerOunce" Column, but I still get a truncated error.

Comment: Every data row is suffixed by a non printing character remove them and I can get the data to load - I suggest you copy and edit the first few rows an try importing that whilst I have a think about how to fix the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your csv file with notepad an click at the end of the first data row you should see that there is a character between the last digit in caloriesperounce and the cursor. This seems to extend all the way down, I have no idea what this character is or what you may have done to put it it there. The quickest fix I can get is to import the csv file into excel (if you add a column with the following formula =LEN(B1) you should see that all the caloriesperounce are 1 bigger than expected). You can then add a column =(MID(B1,1,LEN(B1)-1))to strip out the extra character. Copy and paste values the first column and the column you have just created to another worksheet and save this as a comma separated file. Open this new file with notepad to check that there is no non printing character at the end of each data row. If ok try importing to mysql.

Some further information - if you add a column =CODE(MID(B2,LEN(B2),1)) and copy down you will see the last column has an ascii code of 160 which is a space character - this is unusual because normally a space would have an ascii code of 32 (see http://www.asciitable.com/) Did you download this data from a website or did you type it with a weird keyboard?

and I think you can =SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(160),"") to rid yourself of this bothersome character

Comment: Thank you so much, this was so frustrating. I really appreciate you taking the time to figure this out for me!